# How can I use JavaFX 8 to do zoom operations with several nodes together

Tags: javafx

everyone. I am new in JavaFX, I have one problem maybe easier for you but spent me a lot of time, I still can not figure out. My problem is this:

I need to implement a swatch GUI with Java Scene Builder. I choose class **Circle** as swatch dial,  and choose class **Label** to as time index(1, 2, 3, ... 12), and choose class **Line** as hour hand, minute hand and second hand.

When I want to do zoom in zoom out operations, I want that the **Label(time Indexes)** and the **Line(swatch hands)** can be the children of the **Circle(swatch dial)**, but it seems can not.
So, is there any method can zoom in or zoom out together this several nodes together?

Answer (score 1):

Put all the nodes in a `Group` and apply the zoom to the `Group`.

Something like

```
Pane mainContainer = ... ;
Group watch = new Group();
Circle dial = new Circle(...);
Line hourHand = ... ;
Line minuteHand = ... ;
watch.getChildren().addAll(dial, hourHand, minuteHand);
Label[] timeLabels = new Label[12];
for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
    timeLabels[i-1]= new Label(String.valueOf(i));
    watch.getChildren().add(timeLabels[i-1]);
}
mainContainer.getChildren().add(watch);
```

Obviously you need to position the various pieces.

Then to zoom just do

```
watch.setScaleX(...);
watch.setScaleY(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.But it's still a little bit strange. The first zoom out operation works well, but if continue zoom out, there is no change in the view. I  noticed the listener detect the corresponding Scroll event, and setScaleX()/setScalY() works well. But the view is just no change. Is there any constraints there?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a different question, as I think it is a different issue. Also, you should post a simple code example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much for your advice. I will try to describe my question more clear.